# Does orderBy only work the first time with ng-options?

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 select lists and you can pick from the list of all things (select list A) and put them in your basket (select list B).

The select statement looks like:

```
<select multiple
 ng-options="thing as thing.display for thing in mythings|orderBy:display" 
 ng-model="selectedThings"></select>
```

Where `$scope.mythings` are the things in my basket.  My problem is that orderBy:display appears to only work the first time (the list is sorted when the dialog displays) but does not stay sorted as I put things into the basket.  Everything just appends to the existing list (just like the `.push` I'm using to get things into `mythings`.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle showing this?

Comment: What about using `$filter('orderBy')` to order `mythings` after using `push`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `orderBy:'display'`

```
<select multiple
        ng-options="thing as thing.display for thing in mythings | orderBy:'display'" 
        ng-model="selectedThings">
</select>
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/hbELP/)